# Does solidity revert global variables if function call fails?

Tags: solidity, require

I was reading about reentrancy attacks in smart contracts from here: https://ethereum-contract-security-techniques-and-tips.readthedocs.io/en/latest/known_attacks/ . Here they suggest that in order to avoid reentrancy attacks, we should first finish all the internal work of the function before calling an external function. This was a correct code as per them which prevents such attack:

```
mapping (address => uint) private userBalances;

function withdrawBalance() public {
    uint amountToWithdraw = userBalances[msg.sender];
    userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;
    require(msg.sender.call.value(amountToWithdraw)()); // The user's balance is already 0, so future invocations won't withdraw anything
}
```

In this code, suppose `msg.sender.call.value()` fails due to some reason, and thus the `require()` check fails. But `userBalances[msg.sender]` has already been set to 0 by this time. So my question is, will `userBalances[msg.sender]` get reverted to it's original value (non zero) in case `require()` check fails?

Answer (score 1):

YES, you can see in [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) it says:

> Solidity uses state-reverting exceptions to handle errors. Such an exception undoes all changes made to the state in the current call (and all its sub-calls) and flags an error to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

in your case it will revert - yes. this is because the `call` method will return `false` as first argument and then `require(false)` will halt & revert any changes.